# How to get uproot.iterate() output like the root_numpy root2array() output fast

Tags: uproot

`array2root` returns a list of tuples with a dtype containing the branch names. Is there a way to return the same type of format from `uproot.iterate()` without costly reshaping it afterwards?

Output should be the same as from

```
array = root2array(['file.root'], treename = 'tree', branches = ['pt', 'eta'])
```

Which goes like `np.array([(pt0, eta0), (pt1, eta1), ... dtype=[('pt', '<f4'), ('eta', '<f4')]]`

Comment: could you add the image as code please? It will make your question more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an upper bound on how large the array can be (i.e. you're getting it from `iterate`, so you can pass `entrysteps=10000` and know that it will never be larger than `10000`), then you can preallocate your array and pass it to uproot and have uproot fill that instead of creating new arrays. In your case, you can make it a record array:

```py
buffer = numpy.empty(20000, dtype=[("pt", "f8"), ("eta", "f8")])
pt_buffer = buffer["pt"]
eta_buffer = buffer["eta"]
```

The `pt_buffer` and `eta_buffer` are views of the `buffer`, which happen to be interleaved, but they work just as well as arrays. (The reason that I have allocated `20000`, rather than just `10000`, will be explained below.)

Now say that you're interested in two branches whose default `interpretation` is `uproot.asdtype(">f8", "f8")`. Request these arrays with interpretation `uproot.asarray(">f8", pt_buffer)` and `uproot.asarray(">f8", eta_buffer)`. The first argument is the Numpy dtype that will be used to interpret the raw data from the ROOT file (big-endian, hence the `">"`) and the second argument is the array you're going to read the data into, in-place.

```py
for arrays in tree.iterate({"pt": uproot.asarray(">f8", pt_buffer),
                            "eta": uproot.asarray(">f8", eta_buffer)},
                           outputtype=tuple, entrysteps=10000):
    start = int((arrays[0].ctypes.data - buffer.ctypes.data) / buffer.itemsize)
    stop = start + len(arrays[0])
    array_of_tuples = buffer[start:stop]
    print(array_of_tuples)
```

See [the documentation](https://uproot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interpretation.html#uproot-interp-numerical-asarray) on this rarely used and not widely advertised feature.

Even though `iterate` is filling and sending you arrays in a dict called `arrays`, they're column-views of the `buffer` record array ("array of tuples"). By looking at the original `buffer`, we see the structure that you want.

However, uproot actually fills `buffer` with whole-basket contents, starting at the beginning of the first relevant basket and ending at the end of the last relevant basket to cover each subrange: `[0, 10000)`, `[10000, 20000)`, `[20000, 30000)`, etc. Therefore the part of `buffer` that you want may start several entries in (`start != 0`) and will likely end before `20000` (`stop - start != len(buffer)`). Since `arrays[0]` is a view of the first column in `buffer` containing only the entries that you do want, the difference between `arrays[0].ctypes.data` and `buffer.ctypes.data` is the number of bytes into `buffer` that you want. Dividing by `buffer.itemsize` gives the number of entries. The ending position is easier to calculate.

The preallocation of `buffer` has to be big enough to include all the entries you do want and any additional entries that come along with a basket and need to be cut off. `20000` is safe if no basket is larger than `10000`. For a given `tree`, you can determine the largest number of entries in any basket of any branch with:

```py
max(branch.basket_numentries(i) for branch in tree.values()
                                for i in range(branch.numbaskets))
```

Clearly, that's not what these functions were designed for: `asarray` was meant for performance, to avoid reallocating big arrays like `buffer`. It was assumed, however, that you'd want data in columns: the `arrays[0]` and `arrays[0]` sent to the body of the for loop. In the above, we *additionally* want to look at the data formatted as a record array ("array of tuples"), so we're actually looking at this "dumping ground" known as `buffer`. To do that sensibly—avoiding the entries not relevant for this subrange—we have to explicitly cut them out, and there weren't any functions in the library for figuring out where that subrange is. However, this

```py
    start = int((arrays[0].ctypes.data - buffer.ctypes.data) / buffer.itemsize)
    stop = start + len(arrays[0])
    array_of_tuples = buffer[start:stop]
```

would be a general implementation of such a function.

Comment: Warning: the above is untested—typed into a phone from memory. If you find any errors in it, let's fix it for posterity. Thanks!

Comment: I am looking to replace a root_numpy piece of code to get rid of the ROOT dependency, but would like to avoid changing the rest of the rather large codebase. Performance is important due to the converted dataset size.

Comment: The above approach still seems to return a tuple of arrays rather than an array of tuples like [(pt1, eta1), (pt2, eta2)...] But also ```gen_u =  uproot.iterate(['infile.root'], 
                                'tree',
                                {"fj_pt": uproot.asarrtay(">f8", pt_buffer),
                                 "fj_eta": uproot.asarray(">f8", eta_buffer)},
                                outputtype=tuple, entrysteps=10000)``` throws the following `ValueError: cannot put 10359 items into an array of 10000 items`

Comment: In the above method, the `buffer` is filled in place with the data, and by construction, the `buffer` is a record array (an "array of tuples"). I'll change the answer to access the original `buffer`, rather than the separate-column views of it.

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I've been looking for except for an Assertion error while running `iterate` https://gist.github.com/andrzejnovak/f920a66f2f30c8502d199382556cc16b Setting different entry steps doesn't seem to make a difference, buffer larger than the file size also. Seems to happen half way through the number of events in the file.

Comment: I need to change that error message from `assert remainder == 0` to something like "this Interpretation is not valid for this branch" (because the sizes don't line up). In my example above, I was assuming that they're 8-byte float (i.e. `double`) branches; if they're 4-byte floats (i.e. `float`), then you want `f4` and not `f8`. You're replacing `asdtype` with `asarray`, but keeping the dtypes the same. If this worked for one file and not another, it could have been that you need `f4` and your first file had an even number of events. Check the default `branch.interpretation`!